# attaching id to a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, properties

I have a loop that creates mc from a database

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < t.length; i++) {


var portfolioItem:PortfolioItem = new PortfolioItem();
addChild(portfolioItem);
portfolioItem.name = t[i][0];
portfolioItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getThisName);

}
public function getThisName(evt:Event) {
trace(evt.target.name);
}
```

I try and assign t[i][0] which is the table id to the name attribute but I jsut get 'instance4' or instance 14. How can I give these dynamically create mc's a name or custom property?

ideally I would like to use a custom property called portfolio.id but would use the name property or another default property if it works.

Comment: Does your code work if you just try adding a normal MovieClip? I can't see any reason why the code that is there wouldn't do what you'd like it to. The problem might be with how you've got the PortfolioItem class setup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that t[i][0] is resolving to a valid String each time it is encountered?  As an aside, i:Number could be better off as i:int.